# Favorite tag questions highlighting lacks contrast with tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, favorite-tag

When you add a tag to your favorites, any question that has that tag is automatically highlighted in question lists, with the color #faf1e4. Problem is, the tags are almost exactly the same color (#f9f1e6). This, coupled with the fact that our tags do not have a border all the way around them (only on the left and right sides) make the tags blend in with the question box in a very confusing way.

[image: Screenshot.]

To fix this, we could change the color that favorite tag questions are highlighted with. For example, changing the highlighting color to something closer to #f8e1bf, would make the tags noticeably different, and it matches with the upper bar (perhaps too much, but then, it's just an example).

Comment: Note that this problem does not exist here on meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have darkened the favorite tagged background color a bit for better contrast. The change will be in the next production build.

Comment: Thanks Jin, but now the text that says how recently the entry was edited is a little hard to read on the darkened background.  Would it be possible to darken that too?

Comment: @MonicaCellio yes I'll darken that text

Comment: @MonicaCellio the darkened text is now on live.

Comment: Jin, that's much better.  Thanks!